# Global bounded solution of $u_{tt}=\Delta u-mu+h$ in the Hilbert space $X=H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\times L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Consider the linear wave equation
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}u\left(t,x\right)=\Delta u\left(t,x\right)-mu\left(t,x\right)+h\left(t,x\right), & t\geq0, \ x\in \Omega \\
u\left(0,x\right)=\phi\left(x\right)\mbox{ and }\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}u\left(0,x\right)=\psi\left(x\right), & x\in\Omega.
\end{cases}$$
 where $m\in \mathbb{R}$ and $h:[0,+\infty)\times \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the Hilbert space $X=H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\times L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$ equipped with the scalar product
$$\left\langle \left(\begin{array}{c}
u\\
v
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
w\\
z
\end{array}\right)\right\rangle =\int_{\Omega}\left(\nabla u.\nabla w+muw+vz\right)dx.$$
If we assume that $h\in L^{\infty}([0,+\infty),L^2(\Omega))$, is there any sufficient condition on the parameters of the equation which assures the existence of a global bounded solution i.e. 
$$\sup_{t\geq 0}\left\|(u,u_t) \right\|_X<+\infty. $$

I am also interested if someone knows some reference which deals with bounded global solutions of linear non-autonomous equations where the differential operator generates an isometry group of operators, which is the case for the above wave equation or for example Schrödinger equations.

Comment: $m$ is a constant?

Comment: @JasonKnapp Yes, it is a constant.

Comment: I'm sorry to do this to you, I have another clarification.  No boundary conditions: deliberate?  Also I assume the other gradient factor in the inner product is $w$, not $v$.

Comment: $H^1_0$ - homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions I suppose

Comment: If $(\phi,\psi) \in X$ then the desired bound holds. If you know about existence of solutions, the bound can be obtained by testing the weak formulation with $u_t$ and $\Delta u$. Evans' book on pde is a good reference.

Comment: @JasonKnapp Apparently the book I am reading made this typo:$w$ instead of $v$, I will correct it. And yes I only want the solution $(u,u_t)$ to be in $X=H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\times L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$, so $H_{0}^{1}$ homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions as daw said.

Comment: @daw is that true with just $h(t) \in L^2(\Omega)$?  I was thinking that approach would ask more from $h$.

Comment: @JasonKnapp The book I am reading proves this for the equation: $$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}u\left(t,x\right)=\Delta u\left(t,x\right)-mu\left(t,x\right)-\gamma \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}u\left(t,x\right)+h\left(t,x\right), & t\geq0, \ x\in \Omega \\
u\left(0,x\right)=\phi\left(x\right)\mbox{ and }\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}u\left(0,x\right)=\psi\left(x\right), & x\in\Omega.
\end{cases}$$, where $\gamma>0$. What I want is the case $\gamma=0$, I think it is better to include these information in the post.

Comment: @user50618 so $m$ is not necessarily positive?

Comment: @daw not neccessarly, I just want some sufficient condition on the parameters $m,\Omega,\phi,\psi$ to unsure the existence of a global bounded solution.

Comment: I don't know how I can include the PDF for the book. It is on page 139  Theorem 8.4.5, From google:http://books.google.co.ma/books?id=pltEngEACAAJ&dq=haraux+cazenave&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4RnhU8O9MZOY1AXtyIGoAg&redir_esc=y

Comment: I would second Evans as a good general resource for this topic.  I think your life will be happier with $m$ positive, you only will need the initial data in the Hilbert space, but I do think you will need $h \in L^1(0,\infty; L^2(\Omega))$.

Comment: @JasonKnapp Maybe the $\gamma>0$ in the orginal theorem helps the solution to be dissipative.

Comment: I may be incorrect but I think you also should have a good start on semigroup theory for Cazenave.  I know there is a summary at the start, but [Brezis](http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analysis-Differential-Equations-Universitext/dp/0387709134/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1407263415&sr=1-1&keywords=brezis+functional+analysis+sobolev+spaces+and+partial+differential+equations) is a very readable source to get started as well. - Or maybe you already do!  Just trying to offer info :)

Comment: @JasonKnapp Thanks, I will look at Brezis and Evans.

Comment: @JasonKnapp The solution has the form $(u,u_t)=S(t)(\phi,\psi)+\int_0^tS(t-s)(0,h(s)ds$, so because $S(t)$ is an isometry group of operators, the condition $h\in L^1$ implies that $|(u,u_t)|\leq |(\phi,\psi)|+\int_0^{+\infty}|h(s)|$, so we have a bounded global solution.

Comment: I am more interested on the case $h\in L^{\infty}(0,+\infty;L^2(\Omega))$

Comment: @user50618 Is that a quote or what you've worked out?  I'm in agreement with that statement.  If you lose integrability then you need a different method to infer boundedness for all time.  Another possibility would be to pick spatially smoother $h$, i.e. $h(t)$ in say $H^2$ and attempt to use exponential decay for smoother solutions coming from the semigroup.  But I do not think you can get your result simply with only bounded in $L^1$.

Comment: @JasonKnapp It is just my statement, I will think about this. Thank you for your attention anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an example. So, look at $\Omega = [0,\pi]\subset \mathbb{R}^{1}$, where you have an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions for $-\Delta=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ given by $\{ e_{n}(x)=\sqrt{2/\pi}\sin(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. To solve the equation in this case, write the solution as
$$
          u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(t)e_{n}(x)
$$
Then
$$
        a_{n}''(t)=-n^{2}a_{n}(t)-ma_{n}(t)+(h(t),e_{n})
$$
The solution of this equation, where $a_{n}(0)$, $a_{n}'(0)$ are known, involves convolution with functions $\exp(\pm i\sqrt{n^{2}+m}\,t)$, and is given by
$$
       a_{n}(t) = a_{n}(0)\cos(\sqrt{n^{2}+m}\,t)
    +a_{n}'(0)\frac{\sin(\sqrt{n^{2}+m}\,t)}{\sqrt{n^{2}+m}} \\
    +\int_{0}^{t}(h(u),e_{n})\frac{\sin(\sqrt{n^{2}+m}\,(t-u))}{\sqrt{n^{2}+m}}\,du.
$$
Regardless of the value of $m$, for sufficiently large $n$, this value has negligible effect on $a_{n}(t)$. So the issue is not the parameter $m$: it is the driving function $h$. And this is the simplest possible example. If any $a_{n}(t)$ grows without bound as $t\rightarrow\infty$, you're in trouble. And controlling the time behavior of $a_{n}$ for large enough (but fixed) $n$ basically has nothing to do with $m$--it has to do with the growth of $(h(u),e_{n})$ as a function of $u$. I think you're barking up the wrong tree, from both the point of view of Mathematics and of Physics. Why? Because you can't expect to push the system forever and not see consequences, unless that tapers off in a predictable manner for every mode of the system, or unless you have some damping (but you threw that term away.)

**Note:** I agree that you get boundedness for the conditions you stated on $h$. That appears to me to be correct, too. The above construction of solution can be carried out using the spectral resolution for $\Delta$ in the general case, too.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It is then the damping $-\gamma u_t$ which makes things bounded on the future.

Comment: You're welcome.